# Trying to work a threshold value into linq query(ies)

Tags: c#, linq, subquery, aggregate

Good Evening everyone,

I've been trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this, but am falling short. Here's how it goes...

I am ultimately trying to determine "like customers" based on a specific customer's buying habits and a given threshold, say 50%. IE customer 1 purchased products A,B,C,D  ... customer 2 purchased B,C,D,E ... these two customers are >= 50% "likeness" so they should be matched.

My schema is as would be expected

```
CLIENT (1 ----- many)  CLIENT_PURCHASE (1 -------many) PRODUCT

*clientID            *clientID *prodID                 *prodID
```

For now I am ignoring the threshold and simply am trying to find customers who have purchased any item within customer 1's history. I think I have this working with the following two queries:

```
var clientOneHistory = (from cp in client.Client_Purchase
                        select cp.prodID).ToList();

var matchedClients = (from cp in db.Client_Purchase
                        where clientOneHistory.Contains(cp.prodID)
                        select cp.Client.fullname).Distinct().ToList();
```

So my ultimate question is, "How do I work in the threshold portion?"
Thanks for your time

Comment: Say customer 1 buys A,B and customer 2 buys A,B,C,D Are they 100% alike or 50% alike?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have been a bit more clear regarding the threshold.

Simply put, I want to compare customer 1's purchases to everyone else's. If customer 1 bought A B, and customer 2 bought A B C D, technically customer 2 would exceed the minimum required threshold of 50%, having bought 100% of customer 1's purchases. 

The total percentage will be out of customer 1's purchases. If customer 2 only purchased A, he would be 50% "like" customer 1. Hope this is clear enough. Please let me know of any other clarifications. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to form these queries for your particular case.  Assuming you want to use LINQ-to-SQL.  Instead, I'll use the NorthWind database as an example to do the same thing.  You could then use the ideas used here in your implementation.  I don't think it's possible to do this completely using LINQ-to-SQL, you'll have to do a mix.

```
var threshold = 0.5M;

// let's pick a customer id
var myId = "VINET";

// get products of current customer
var myProducts = (from c in db.Customers
                  where c.CustomerID == myId
                  join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
                  join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
                  select od.ProductID)
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToArray();

// get the products of all other customers
var others = (from c in db.Customers
              where c.CustomerID != myId
              join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
              join od in db.Order_Details on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
              group od.ProductID by c.CustomerID into g
              select new { CustomerID = g.Key, Products = g.Distinct() })
             .AsEnumerable();

// calculate "likeness" values for each person
var likeness = from o in others
               let Percent = Decimal.Divide(myProducts.Intersect(o.Products).Count(), myProducts.Length)
               where Percent >= threshold
               select new { o.CustomerID, Percent };
```

Comment: After thinking about it, I think you'd be most interested in the last query.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I like the solution. I realized after a bit that when you break it down to its lowest level, I'm basically comparing two lists for common elements, which can be accomplished nicely with the intersect() method. Having that available definitely makes it more feasible/efficient to get the percentage, as which you did nicely. Thanks again